# Change Switch state without animation

Tags: android, android-listview, android-switch

In my Android project, I have a `ListView` with rows containing `SwitchCompat` items (AppCompat for `Switch` widget).

My problem occurs when I scroll into the list and `getView(...)` method of `MyAdapter` is invoked with a `recycled` view. I redefine the correct `Switch` state but the animation is visible.

There is a solution to prevent the animation in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Call `jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()` to skip the animation

```
switchCompat.setChecked(true);
switchCompat.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();
```

Comment: I've found this changes the color of the switch to be active, but it still remains in the 'unchecked' position..

Comment: With data bindings, call `executePendingBindings()` before `jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()`

Comment: This works great for radio buttons / checkboxes if you are scrolling in a list.

Answer (score 10):

I finally found a solution but seems not really clean:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view; // the recycled view
viewGroup.removeView(switch);
switch.setChecked(states[index]);
viewGroup.addView(switch);
```

If a better solution exists, please share it.

Comment: Unfortunately your way appears to be the only one. Looking at the code for `setChecked()` in API 21 `Switch`:  `if (isAttachedToWindow() && isLaidOut()) { animateThumbToCheckedState(checked); }`

Comment: @kcoppock, this code has been changed in SwitchCompat to `if (isAttachedToWindow() && isLaidOut() && isShown())` so it is possible to hide it temporarily:  `switch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); switch.setChecked(); switch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 4):

The issue in with animation playing in the list can be present if you use Android Databinding.

To resolve it, run `binding.executePendingBindings()` method after you set data – it will refresh binding state for the component in current frame and will not wait for the next one to come.

As you have probably guessed already – next frame is the animation

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I managed to solved it using some minimal reflection.

**Usage:**

To change the switch state without animation call the `setChecked(boolean checked, boolean animate)` method with false for the animate parameter. If the switch already is animating at the moment this method is being called the animation will be stopped and the switch jumps to the desired position.

**SwitchCompatFix.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

/**
 * Work around for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139262/change-switch-state-without-animation
 * Possible fix for bug 101107: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=101107
 *
 * Version 0.2
 * @author Rolf Smit
 */
public class SwitchCompatFix extends SwitchCompat {

    public SwitchCompatFix(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initHack();
    }

    public SwitchCompatFix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initHack();
    }

    public SwitchCompatFix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initHack();
    }

    private Method methodCancelPositionAnimator = null;
    private Method methodSetThumbPosition = null;

    private void initHack(){
        try {
            methodCancelPositionAnimator = SwitchCompat.class.getDeclaredMethod("cancelPositionAnimator");
            methodSetThumbPosition = SwitchCompat.class.getDeclaredMethod("setThumbPosition", float.class);
            methodCancelPositionAnimator.setAccessible(true);
            methodSetThumbPosition.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked, boolean animate){
        // Java does not support super.super.xxx calls, a call to the SwitchCompat default setChecked method is needed.
        super.setChecked(checked);
        if(!animate) {

            // See original SwitchCompat source:
            // Calling the super method may result in setChecked() getting called
            // recursively with a different value, so load the REAL value...
            checked = isChecked();

            // Cancel any running animations (started by super.setChecked()) and immediately move the thumb to the new position
            try {
                if(methodCancelPositionAnimator != null && methodSetThumbPosition != null) {
                    methodCancelPositionAnimator.invoke(this);
                    methodSetThumbPosition.invoke(this, checked ? 1 : 0);
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note for proguard users:**

Because this method uses reflection an additional proguard rule might be needed (if not yet present).

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat {
    private void cancelPositionAnimator();
    private void setThumbPosition(float);
}
```

This additional rule is not needed when you're using one of the following proguard rules (or similar ones):

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

Comment: May I ask if you know why in some cases it actually skips the animation of being checked/unchecked ? I've made a library for supporting material design preferences (here: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialPreferenceLibrary ), and I have no idea why it skips the animation and switches directly to the toggled state.

Comment: oh oh reflection

Answer (score 1):

Using SwitchCompat and DataBinding

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:checkedState"})
public static void setCheckedState(SwitchCompat switchView, boolean checked) {
    int visibility = switchView.getVisibility();
    switchView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    switchView.setChecked(checked);
    switchView.setVisibility(visibility);
}
```

Then in xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/my_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:checkedState="@{my_data.checked}"/>
```

And don't forget to call `executePendingBindings()` (thanks [AAverin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453991/aaverin))

Comment: Also consider using `binding.executePendingBindings()` for list elements, because this is the main reason this animation runs on screen – one extra frame of execution

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin developer:

```
fun SwitchCompat.setCheckedWithoutAnimation(checked: Boolean) {
    val beforeVisibility = visibility
    visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    isChecked = checked
    visibility = beforeVisibility
}
```

And the usage:

```
mySwitch.setCheckedWithoutAnimation(true)
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this skips the animation? Because if you look at the code of `SwitchCompat#setChecked` the visibility has no effect on the animation.

Comment: Depending what `LayoutTransition` you have enabled on your parent layout, I think this might still animate, but differently. It should animate from invisible to visible :)

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin sample of [Rolf ツ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1052697/rolf-%E3%83%84) answer.

```
class SwitchImproved(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : SwitchCompat(context, attributeSet) {

    private lateinit var methodCancelPositionAnimator: Method
    private lateinit var methodSetThumbPosition: Method

    init {
        initHack()
    }

    fun setChecked(checked: Boolean, animate: Boolean = true) {
        super.setChecked(checked)

        if (!animate) {
            methodCancelPositionAnimator.invoke(this)
            methodSetThumbPosition.invoke(this, if (isChecked) 1 else 0)
        }
    }

    private fun initHack() {
        methodCancelPositionAnimator = SwitchCompat::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("cancelPositionAnimator")
        methodSetThumbPosition = SwitchCompat::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("setThumbPosition", Float::class.javaPrimitiveType)
        methodCancelPositionAnimator.isAccessible = true
        methodSetThumbPosition.isAccessible = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I am using the new material library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
```

and in the setChecked method of this class there is this condition:

```
if (getWindowToken() != null && ViewCompat.isLaidOut(this))
```

So what I did was to create a class that extends from this SwitchMaterial, and deal with "isLaidOut". The code is the next one (omitting constructors):

```
class SwitchCustomView : SwitchMaterial {

  private var laidOutForAnimation = false

  fun setChecked(checked: Boolean, animate: Boolean) {
    if (!animate) {
      laidOutForAnimation = true
    }
    super.setChecked(checked)
    laidOutForAnimation = false
  }

  override fun isLaidOut(): Boolean {
    return if (laidOutForAnimation) {
      return false
    } else {
      super.isLaidOut()
    }
  }
}
```

Then just use this class in your xml and call programatically

```
setChecked(checked: Boolean, animate: Boolean)
```

Comment: @Vlad at the moment I am using com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta02 and it is working just fine for me. There may be many reasons why it is not working for you. Sadly, I can't help you with the information you are giving.