# Slider Switch in Android

Tags: java, android

I encounter the problem with Switch in android.
Here's my code to handle OnCheckedChangeListener of Switch:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
    if (compoundButton.isPressed()) {
        myCodeHere();
    }
}
```

The condition **if (compoundButton.isPressed())** to avoid onCheckedChanged called automatically. But when I slider Switch then **myCodeHere()** don't trigger.

Please give me some hint to resolve this issue.
Or any way to disable slider of Switch ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
```

Called when the checked state of a compound button has changed. You can use the boolean `isChecked` to perform actions whenever the switch is turned ON/OFF

```
if (isChecked) {
// switch is ON perform some action
} else {
// switch is OFF perform some different action
}
```

Comment: If don't use condition, I will encounter another problem same at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139262/change-switch-state-without-animation

Comment: @KhoaNguyễn: So the problem is animation redrawn, Did u tried the suggested solutions for that problem?

Comment: I tried the way of Mr.alex, but it don't work. Do you have any idea for this issue ?

Comment: @KhoaNguyễn: Well u can try all the suggested answers. Sorry I don't any ideas over it