# CheckBox set checked programmatically without animating

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, checkbox

I have a ListView where each item is a CheckBox. I keep the state of each item in an ArrayList to make sure that the recycled views are not mixed up.

The only problem with that is that I have to use setChecked on each CheckBox row item, which at first shows checked then shows the unchecking animation.

Is there a way to force setChecked on a CheckBox without the animation? Instantly, I mean.

Comment: If you set it when it's not attached to a window, then there will be no animation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139262/change-switch-state-without-animation for more info.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can do this is to use your own check images in the `CheckBox`. You'll need images for the different states which you can obtain from http://android-holo-colors.com/

Then we can reference these drawables in our code as:

```
    Drawable mEnabledBg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_bg_enabled);
    Drawable mCheckedBg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_bg_checked);
    Drawable mDisabledBg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_bg_disabled);
```

Now, we use them in a `StateListDrawbles`:

```
    StateListDrawable tickColorStates = new StateListDrawable();

    tickColorStates.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, mCheckedBg); //checked
    tickColorStates.addState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked, android.R.attr.state_enabled}, mEnabledBg); //un-checked
    tickColorStates.addState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, mDisabledBg); //disabled

    checkBox.setButtonDrawable(tickColorStates);
```

Of course this setup can also be done in xml and you'll simply need to call `setButtonDrawable()` then. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement your own drawables. Just use the method `jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()` like this:

```
private fun setChecked(
    btn: CompoundButton,
    checked: Boolean,
    withTransition: Boolean
) {
    btn.isChecked = checked

    if (!withTransition) {
        btn.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()
    }
}
```